# Change notifier not updating stateless widget page

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-provider

I am trying to update page content when an action is called.
Below is a sample of the code under change notifier that receives the onTap: method, When I click it should update the stateless widget depending on the tab clicked.

```
 MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: ScreenChange()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => UserRepository.instance())
  ],
  child: Consumer<ScreenChange>(
      builder: (context, ScreenChange screenChange, child) {
    return Material(
      child: SafeArea(
        child:
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      screenChange.changeHomeState(PageState.homescreen);
                      print("${screenChange.state}");
                    },
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                          BoxShadow(
                            color:
                                screenChange.state == PageState.homescreen
                                    ? Global.orange
                                    : Colors.transparent,
                            blurRadius: blurRadius,
                            spreadRadius: spreadRadius,
                            offset: const Offset(5, 5),
                          )
                        ]),
                        child: const Icon(
                          FontAwesomeIcons.home,
                          color: Global.yellow,
                        ),
                      ),
                      title: Text(
                        "Home",
                        style: GoogleFonts.acme(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Below is the widget that I want to change/ update:

```
 ChangeNotifierProvider(
                  create: (context) => ScreenChange(),
                  child: Consumer<ScreenChange>(
                      builder: (context, ScreenChange change, child) {
                    switch (change.state) {
                      case PageState.homescreen:
                        print('${change.state}');
                        return Home();
                      case PageState.categories:
                        print('${change.state}');
                        return const CategoryScreen();
                      case PageState.notification:
                        print('${change.state}');
                        return NotificationScreen();
                      default:
                    }
                    return Center(
                        child: Text("Something went wrong",
                            style: GoogleFonts.abel(
                              fontSize: 20,
                            )));
                  }),
                ),
```

Below is my change notifier class:

```
    enum PageState {
  homescreen,
  categories,
  account,
  notification,
  about,
  shareApp
}

class ScreenChange extends ChangeNotifier {
  PageState homeState = PageState.homescreen;
  PageState get state => homeState;
  void changeHomeState(PageState state) {
    homeState = state;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here , I was using
another change notifier provider which did not trigger ,
Therfore my solution: I MOVED MY MULTIPROVIDER ABOVE THE WIDGET I WAS TRING TO UPDATE

https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues/231